# Various questions regarding wallet and mining

Tags: wallet

Ok so I downloaded the bitcoin program and started it up.
And the program started downloading thousands of blocks.
I haven't clicked anything or signed up anywhere, I have tried and i **think** succeeded in finding my address, no sure though.
Now it is still busy downloading blocks.
On the overview screen it shows wallet out of sync.
How do I sync this or does this happen once the blocks are done?
How do I make/get/mine bitcoins, any websites that can be recommended?
Do I have to add my own money to get started?

Answer (score 1):

1) yes, "out of sync" means that it hasn't downloaded the whole blockchain yet.

2) to mine ("make") them, you need special hardware and software.

3) it is much easier, yes. There are many exchanges where you can buy bitcoins, such as [Mt. Gox](https://mtgox.com/) or [Bitcoin Central](https://bitcoin-central.net/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast feedback. I will look into the hardware and software components and see what I have and what I need.